# json from mySql databse to object array conversion

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, json, javascript-objects

Im trying to get an object array from my MySql database, however I keep getting the result of "undefined" and I do not know why
my code:

```
database.query(sql, (err, rows)=>{
    var data = Object.values(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows)))
    console.log(data[0].type)
})
```

Whenever I console log my "data" variable I get:

```
[
  {
    data: '[{"type": "c#", "script": "csharp script"}, {"type": "javascript", "script": "javascript script"}, {"type": "html", "script": "html script"}]'
  }
]
```

which seems correct to me but Im not sure about what to do now.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: First of all, there's no need to stringify then parse again. This does create a copy, but that's pointless here. In theory you need `rows[0].data[0].type` but it seems like `.data` is a string so you need `JSON.parse(rows[0].data)[0].type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual `data` you need is inside the first element's `.data` property. It's a string, so you need to parse it to use as an array of objects.

**Working example**

```js
let yourData = [{
  data: '[{"type": "c#", "script": "csharp script"}, {"type": "javascript", "script": "javascript script"}, {"type": "html", "script": "html script"}]'
}]

let data = JSON.parse(yourData[0].data)
console.log(data[0].type)
```

Comment: Based on the console output, `.data` seems to be JSON, so this won't work.

Comment: I've missed the quotes, answer updated.

Comment: It's a dupe anyway.